# Is there any UI tool within Visual Studio can edit MSBuild conditional constructs?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am using text edit tools (notepad++) to edit ".prop" or ".vcxproj" just because I want to use MSBuild conditional constructs whereas cannot find a UI tool within Visual Studio to do this. Is there anyone knows where I can edit so that generating XML statement like following conditional statement?

```html
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="$(Configuration.StartsWith('MyProject-'))">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So far, I’m afraid there has no UI tool can generate XML statement
>   like the statement above:

1.In VS IDE, for some Elements like `<PreBuildEvent>`: `Right-click Project=> Properties=> write a command in build events(Pre-build event)`, then VS will generate an XML statement like `“<PostBuildEvent>…</PostBuildEvent>”`.

2.And as for vcxproj file, if we create a new configuration for this project, then the IDE will generate a statement like `<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='TestConfiguration|Win32'">`  in .proj file for us.

3.But for the statement you mentioned above, which contains a [Property Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2015#BKMK_String) `(Configuration.StartWith)` ,  currently there seems no valid way to generate it In VS unless we hand-edit it by .proj file. Because the `Configuration.StartsWith('…'))` is a custom statement so no UI-combination In VS can generate such statement(with function) in .proj file. Sorry for this inconvenience.

> In addition:

1.Usually, we can edit the .proj file within VS ide by `Right-click Project=>Unload Poeject=>Edit xx.xxproj file`. The editor in vs will help check if elements we type in proj file are correct, I think it may be more suitable for hand-editing. After that, `Right-Click Project and choose Reload` to get files loaded.

2.For .props file, also we can open and edit it in vs by `File=>open` or just `drag it into VS window`.

3.And about `Configuration.StartWith()`, if we have a customed Configuration named “MyProject-“, then the return value is true, otherwise, it would be false. So if what you want is to set the condition by projectName, maybe `ProjectName.StartsWith()` can be more suitable.
Hope all above helps. Look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool in Visual Studio to create conditions. You will just have to do it yourself.

But don't worry, using Notepad++ your results will be cleaner, leaner, less verbose and about 10% the size of what visual studio could possibly do for you.

Comment: See the other answer as well: the text editor in Visual Studio is actually pretty good overall, and it also has completion for MSbuild files which is very convenient since you don't have to remember all those builtin property names by heart or reach for a browser to look them up.

Comment: That's true that visual studio has a pretty good text editor. Especially for MSBuild files. But there is no GUI nor tool for that sort of stuff.