# Is there a way to hookup npm task while running aspnet core application in visual-studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, msbuild-target

I have an Asp.Net core application with WebpackDevMiddleware integrated to it. That WebpackDevMiddleware serves the client assets built with NPM command. Now I want to build and serve those client assests (JS/CSS) simultaneously when project runs.

The obvious solution I thought was to add (pre-build event command line) in project and provide npm command with it. The downside of that is when I build the docker image of my application, using dotnet core sdk, it asks for node environment which it doesn't have.

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
   <Exec Command="npm run build-webpack" />
</Target>
```

and this is my docker build step that doesn't recognize NPM command associated with dotnet build/publish

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c $ENVIRONMENT -o ../out
```

Now what I actually want is, my target only to be executed while running application in VS. A condition might work but what could it be?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean " it asks for node environment which it doesn't have.", a build error? Could you share some error message if it exists.

Comment: The target you use is Equivalent to: 1.open cmd.exe 2.cd the project folder 3. enter command:npm run build-webpack, so the build will succeed unless the command in cmd.exe succeeds.

Comment: I actually got a hint from this [post of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432646/is-there-any-ui-tool-within-visual-studio-can-edit-msbuild-conditional-construct/54435962#54435962)
Can I use a Condition for my target based on an environment variable? So while dockerizing my app I wont provide that env variable and the target doesn't get executed. But while running with VS, I set that variable and hence that target gets executed

Comment: I have provided a bit more context in the question.

Comment: I think what you want is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2019#build-solutions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now what I actually want is, my target only to be executed while
>   running application in VS. A condition might work but what could it
>   be?

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2019#build-solutions): When building inside Visual Studio, the property `$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)` is set to true. This can be used in your project or .targets files to cause the build to behave differently.

So your target will look like:

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true'" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
   <Exec Command="npm run build-webpack" />
</Target>
```

Then this target will only execute when building in VS.

Comment: Glad to know it helps :)